# Having trouble running flask application

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am new to using Flask. Tried to run the basic flask app but results in neither an error nor any output. Can anyone help me to resolve the same?

Code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello, World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

console:

```
 * Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
```

I'm not getting `*Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (press ctrl+c to quit)`.

Can anyone help me on this, please?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Show us your code?

Comment: from flask import Flask

app = Flask(name)

@app.route("/") def hello(): return "Hello, World!"

if name == 'main': app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)

Comment: @srikanth Chekuri I have commented the code above

Comment: I am not getting any errors

Comment: Did you, perchance, open your web browser and go to http://127.0.0.1:5000/ ? What message came up in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

You forgot the underscores.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: It is very unlikely that this was the error. Because the missing underscores came from a wrongly formatted question. It is now fixed.

Comment: How is it fixed? Why not share if you know what could cause it? My guess was that the wrongly formatted question was also the way the code was written.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean the issue was fixed, just the formatting of the question. The missing underscores could not be the problem anyway, because `name` (without underscores) is not defined in the namespace and therefore a `NameError` would be thrown. But since no syntax error was thrown in the output of the python script, it rules out a solution that refers to missing underscores.

Comment: hi, thanks for your response.I was facing the issue using jupyter notebook but the issue was fixed when I ran the same code in Visual Studio Code,

Comment: @AnnMary - you can answer and accept your own question if you want (if this was the problem and the solution, of course).

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello, world!"

if  __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Please compare your own code with mine, there were some things you left out.

Comment: This is a very vague answer, where extra effort has to be done to see what your changes are. It is also very unlikely that this was the error. Because the missing underscores came from a wrongly formatted question. It is now fixed.